# how can I select data in data in db from table products which has products.quantity > sum(product_orders.quantity) ? Using laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3

### **I have table products:**

### -      products     -

- +product_id      -
- +product_name    -
- +quantity        -

  ### -  +unit_price      -

### **Table Orders**

### -      orders       -

- +order_id        -
- +quantity        -
- +date            -

  ### -  +product_id      -

I want to get data of products.* which has sum(orders.quantity) > products.quantity groupBy product_id

Comment: You have to make relation first in product or order table. See the documentation first https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I already put the relationship for that table. can you show me your code?